# How to enable Debug level logging in Log4J (in Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, log4j

I see a lot of code with the following check in Hadoop:

if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
 ...

I guess this is related with log4j? How can I enable Debug level logging in Hadoop?

I see a log4j property file in conf directory of Hadoop and I see some lines like these:

# Custom Logging levels

hadoop.metrics.log.level=INFO

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=DEBUG
  #log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker=DEBUG
  #log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSNamesystem=DEBUG

So is this a matter of uncommenting some entries here I guess?

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821134/hadoop-enable-logging

Answer (score 4):

set

```
HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console
```

in hadoop-env.sh

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550030/2163429

Answer (score -1):

In windows 10 with Hadoop 3.3.1 we can enable it by apending the hadoop-env.cmd with

set HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console