# how to attach debugger to remote Hadoop instance

Tags: debugging, hadoop, jdb

I am not looking for these so-called "[debugging](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDebugMapReducePrograms)" solutions which rely on [println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695991/how-can-i-debug-hadoop-map-reduce).  I mean to attach a *real* debugger to a running Hadoop instance, and debugging it from a different machine.

Is this possible? How? jdb?

Comment: How will you know which task tracker you want to attach to? Or is that unimportant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nicely given at [LINK](http://srinathsview.blogspot.in/2012/05/debugging-hadoop-task-tracker-job.html)

To debug task tracker, do following steps.

1. Edit conf/hadoop-env.sh to have following

   export HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_OPTS="-Xdebug   -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5000,server=y,suspend=n"
2. Start Hadoop (bin/start-dfs.sh and bin/start-mapred.sh)
3. It will block waiting for debug connection
4. Connect to the server using Eclipse "Remote Java Application" in the Debug configurations and add the break points
5. Run a map reduce Job

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it that way as I'd rather my "real" jobs run unhindered by debug-overhead (which can, under circumstances, change the environment conditions anyway): I debug "locally" against  a pseudo-instance (normal debugging in eclipse is absolutely no problem), copying specific files from the live environment once I've isolated (by using e.g. counters) where the problem lies.